# How to Spring Boot understand URL is String?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am having trouble pass the url value. Spring boot don't understand url is String

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add/{id}/{x}/{y}/{name}/{url}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void addGeometry(
        @PathVariable(name="id") Integer id,
        @PathVariable(name="x") float x,
        @PathVariable(name="y") float y,
        @PathVariable(name="name") String name,
        @PathVariable(name="url") String url) {
  System.out.println("Received POST request:" + x);
  System.out.println("Received POST request:" + y);
  System.out.println("Received POST request url:" + url);
    mypointSer.add(id,x,y,name,url);
}
```

Service:

```
public void add(Integer id,float x, float y,String name,String url) {
    mypointrepo.addSPCTY(id,x,y,name,url);
}
```

Repository:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "insert into test (id,geom,name,url) values (:id,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:x, :y), 4326),:name,:url)", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
void addSPCTY( @Param("id") Integer id,@Param("x") float x, @Param("y") float y,@Param("name") String ten,@Param("url") String url);
```

Test - Method POST:

```
http://localhost:9090/add/49/106.62639994087715/11.00448399644145/name/https://i.imgur.com/YXmYCDc.png
```

Error: 404

Please Help Me. Tks all

Comment: A PathVariable can not contain slashes (without further configuration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a URL as a param in another URL.
So what happens is due the `https://i.imgur.com/..` url slash `/` in the actual URL it does not match with your url provided in `@RequestMapping`

`/add/{id}/{x}/{y}/{name}/{url}`
`/add/49/106.62639994087715/11.00448399644145/name/https://i.imgur.com/YXmYCDc.png`

You have two options

1. pass a encoded url in url param to your actual URL so that it doesn't have slash
   `http://localhost:9090/add/49/106.62639994087715/11.00448399644145/name/https%3A%2F%2Fi.imgur.com%2FYXmYCDc.png`
2. Don't pass such param in URL and accept a JSON in your request

   Something like this

   ```json
   {
       "id": 49,
       "x": 106.6263994087715,
       "y": 11.00448399644145,
       "name": "name",
       "url": "https://i.imgur.com/YXmYCDc.png"
   }
   ```

   So your actual URL will be only `http://localhost:9090/add`

Comment: Please refer this it might give you little more idea http://www.dailycodebuffer.com/springs-requestbody-and-responsebody-annotations/

Answer (score 0):

You have to URL encode the URL to pass it as a param in the URL. You can read more about URL encoding in the link [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm)